# How to use gsl::span to fix No array to pointer decay warning?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

I am attempting to resolve the following warning.

```
warning C26485: Expression 'pNMLink->item.szUrl':
No array to pointer decay. (bounds.3...)
```

This warning is caused by the following code.

```
auto pNMLink = reinterpret_cast<PNMLINK>(pNMHDR);
ShellExecuteW(nullptr, L"open", pNMLink->item.szUrl, nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

The extremely limited documentation of the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) suggests that the solution is to use a span.

```
array decay -- use span (from the GSL)
```

Unfortunately, it gives no information on how to construct that span from the array.

I have tried the following.

```
gsl::span<wchar_t> url(pNMLink->item.szUrl);
```

I have tried a number of other options as well. **They all result in the same exact warning**. What magical incantation do I need to use to avoid the warning?

Comment: Not sure about `span` but the way to avoid array decay that I know of is to pass it by reference.  For example `(&pNMLink->item.szUrl)[L_MAX_URL_LENGTH]` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would appear to be an error in the static analysis tool. How do I know? Because you don't get this warning if you do this:

```
int arr[10];
gsl::span<int> sp1(arr);
```

But you do get the warning if you do this:

```
struct Arr { int arr[10]; };
Arr test;
gsl::span<int> sp2(test.arr);
```

`gsl::span` has a constructor that takes array parameters by reference, so when you pass an array directly, there should be no decaying. As shown by `sp1`, which gives no warning. And there's no C++ reason why fetching the array from a struct would provoke decay when using an automatic variable does not.

So clearly, this is a bug in the analysis tool, a false positive.